# Apache Kafka and Nifi for processing a VCF file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, vcftools

I am trying to parse a VCF file using the Apache Kafka and Nifi tools, basically the VCF is available in a file system and I have to acquire and parse to extract the different attributes from it. Is it advisable to use Apache Kafka and/or Nifi for implemention?

Comment: Both will work. What issues are you having?

Comment: There are two meanings of VCF: VCF the contact format and Variant Call Format which is a genomics file format. Which is this?